# why TriggerComplete event not firing?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

When I'm executing the

`context.Scheduler.TriggerJob(jobName, "jobGroup");`

in the (TriggerComplete) event of ITriggerListener after completing the corresponding job this event is not raised again ? whats the problem of executing a job in this event ?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to see the code that you are using to trigger the job, however I think that the TriggerComplete event fires only when the Trigger successfully triggers or BEGINS executing the job.  That means, if you add the TriggerListener after the job is executed, you likely will not see the TriggerComplete event fired.

Verify that you have added an appropriate TriggerListener to the scheduler well before the actual scheduled trigger time.